Extract part of text from a variable declared Bigquery regexp_extract
I have a declared variable in bigquery with words that I want to identify in a table
DECLARE words_to_find DEFAULT r'(CASA|PERRO|CORAZON|GALLETA)';

WITH tabla AS
(    select 1 as row_id, 'QUIERO IR CASA' as name union all
    select 2 as row_id, 'PERRO BONITO' as name union all
    select 3 as row_id, 'GRANDE CORAZON' as name union all
    select 4 as row_id, 'LA GALLETA' as name
)

SELECT
  *
FROM tabla




row_id
name




1
QUIERO IR CASA


2
PERRO BONITO


3
GRANDE CORAZON


4
LA GALLETA



I would like to extract the words that match the declared variable from the column "name", and save them in a new column, it would be something like this



row_id
name
result




1
QUIERO IR CASA
CASA


2
PERRO BONITO.
PERRO


3
GRANDE CORAZON
CORAZON


4
LA GALLETA.
GALLETA



Thanks for your help
How Can I achieve this? I try using REGEXP_EXTRACT but didn't work.

What do you want in result if "name" doesn't contain one of the words to find?  What do you want in result if "name" contains MORE than one of the words to find?
You said you tried REGEXP_EXTRACT but it didn't work. Can you update your post with WHAT you tried and HOW it didn't work?

You have not provided the code you tried which produced the error or what the error was.
DECLARE words_to_find DEFAULT r'(CASA|PERRO|CORAZON|GALLETA)';

WITH tabla AS (
  select 1 as row_id, 'QUIERO IR CASA' as name union all
  select 2 as row_id, 'PERRO BONITO' as name union all
  select 3 as row_id, 'GRANDE CORAZON' as name union all
  select 4 as row_id, 'LA GALLETA' as name union all
  select 5 as row_id, 'SOMETHING ELSE' as name union all
  select 6 as row_id, 'MULTIPLE MATCHES OF STRINGS CASA CORAZON' as name UNION ALL
  select 7 as row_id, 'test lower case mi casa es su casa' as name
)

SELECT
  row_id,
  name, 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(UPPER(name), words_to_find) AS result
FROM tabla

returns



row_id
name
result




1
QUIERO IR CASA
CASA


2
PERRO BONITO
PERRO


3
GRANDE CORAZON
CORAZON


4
LA GALLETA
GALLETA


5
SOMETHING ELSE
null


6
MULTIPLE MATCHES OF STRINGS CASA CORAZON
CASA


7
test lower case mi casa es su casa
CASA



Using REGEXP_CONTAINS will return TRUE or FALSE for matches, if you wanted to do something with the values that returned at least 1 match.
